# Change XAML to c# code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, code-behind

I am trying to change a data template of buttons from WPF XAML to c# code I.E. I want to create the buttons programatically in a .cs file.

The XAML looks like this:

```
<ItemsControl DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Things}}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="buttons" Margin="0">

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <local:FishEyePanel ScaleToFit="false"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
          <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Command="Open" Tag="{Binding XPath=@Tag, Path=Value}" Margin="5" Padding="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="{Binding XPath=@Width}" Height="{Binding XPath=@Height}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

</ItemsControl>
```

The line:

```
<Button Command="Open" Tag="{Binding XPath=@Tag, Path=Value}" Margin="5" Padding="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="{Binding XPath=@Width}" Height="{Binding XPath=@Height}"/>
```

is where I bind all the buttons to a xml file, here is the file:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="Things" XPath="Things/Thing">
   <x:XData>
      <Things xmlns="">
         <Thing Button="uno1" Tag="abc"  Width="200" Height="200"/>
      </Things>
   </x:XData>
</XmlDataProvider>
```

But what I want is instead of calling the xml file with all the bottoms predefined, call a method in cs with the buttons, something like this:

```
public void createButtons()
{
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Tag = "I am from cs";
    buttons.Items.Add(button);
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work about our `createButtons()` method? In general, everything that's possible in XAML is also possible in C# code.

Comment: why do you want to do that? what is wrong about using XAML?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  What have you tried?  If there's a point in coding it that you're hung up on, please ask about that.  If you want somewhere to get started, look at `buttons.ItemContainerStyle` and `buttons.ItemsPanel`, look at their types, and go from there.  It doesn't make too much sense to me why you want to do this in the first place.  If you explain why you want to do this, someone might be able to suggest a better approach.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - not exactly **everything** could be implemented in C#. I'm remember exactly but there was a problem with `DataTemplates` or something related to Templates in general. This person @Fernando-Santiago tries to open a door to something he/she will regret very quickly :)

Comment: I am trying to make this because i need to add buttons dynamically, I dont know how to do it in WPF but in c# i can do it. Thanks to @Tim S. for giving me a start point for search

Comment: Do you want one button for each `Thing` in `Things`?  If so, it looks like that's what your code is already made (trying at least) to do, and I'd recommend doing that all in XAML, if possible.  If it's a much more complicated relationship than that, I'd try to replace your `<Button Command="Open"...` with a user control that has code to dynamically generate the appropriate buttons based on its DataContext when its `Loaded` event triggers.  That way you have the flexibility of using code to generate or show/hide the right elements, while still declaring most things in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need C# to have dynamic buttons per se.

I have an app in production that has dynamic buttons (you can have different buttons add more, etc, all in code and they are just displayed in the WPF UI)

You just need to create a ButtonViewModel object and then put a list of ButtonViewModel in your code.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Setup.Common;

namespace ExampleOfButtonList
{
    public class ButtonViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region Member fields
        protected bool _IsVisible;
        protected bool _IsEnabled;
        protected RelayCommand _ButtonCommand;
        protected String _Text;
        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        /// <summary>
        /// The default constructor
        /// </summary>
        public ButtonViewModel()
        {
        }
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public virtual ICommand ButtonCommand
        {
            get { return _ButtonCommand; }
            set
            {
                _ButtonCommand = value as RelayCommand;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ButtonCommand");
            }
        }

        public bool IsVisible
        {
            get { return _IsVisible; }
            set
            {
                _IsVisible = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsVisible");
            }
        }

        public String Text
        {
            get { return _Text; }
            set
            {
                _Text = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Text");
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Create the list like this in your code:

```
List<ButtonViewModel> buttonList = new List<ButtonViewModel>();
ButtonViewModel bvm1 = new ButtonViewModel();
bvm.ButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(f => SomeMethod());
buttonList.add(bvm1);
```

Note: You can get RelayCommand from any MVVM framework or here: [MVVM Base.zip](http://www.rhyous.com/2011/02/04/a-hello-world-template-of-a-wpf-application-using-mvvm/)

Then use an ItemsControl and bind its ItemsSource to your buttonList and it will properly display the list.